# How to show the content of javascript code in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've this HTML with some javascript and I'm not able to display the result in the browser. Expected is to display just the following key values after the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link id="mystylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 class="city"></h1>
  </div>
  <script>
    const iconCodes = {
      '01d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '01n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '02d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '02n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '03d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '03n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '04d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '04n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '09d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '09n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '10d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '10n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '11d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '11n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '13d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/13d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '13n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/13n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '50d': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/50d@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
      '50n': '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/50n@2x.png" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle">',
    }

    let urlJsonString = $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=39.74362&lon=-8.80705&exclude=hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid=ecef7e88947b6303121bb900373e41d2", function (data) {
      const urlObj = JSON.parse(url)
      const getData = ({ dt, temp, weather: [{ description, icon }] }) => {
        if (temp.day) temp = temp.day
        return { dt, temp, description, icon };
      }
      const { current, daily } = urlObj;
      const result = [getData(current)]
      daily.forEach(obj => result.push(getData(obj)));

      result += `Temperature: ${obj.temp} ºC<br>
        Day: ${obj.dt}<br>
        Description: ${obj.description}<br>
        ${iconCodes[obj.icon]}<br><br>`
    });
    $(".city").html(result);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I expected:

> Temperature: 15.3 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:38:09 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: overcast clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 13.84 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:39:36 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: overcast clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 14.17 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:41:02 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: broken clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 17.29 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:42:28 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: few clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 17.42 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:43:55 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: scattered clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 17.37 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:45:21 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: clear sky - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 17.35 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:46:48 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: scattered clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes
>
> Temperature: 18.13 ºC Day: Tue Jan 20 1970 01:48:14 GMT+0100 (Western
> European Standard Time) Description: overcast clouds - and the weather image from const iconCodes

And this is a exemple of return on console (it is an array of 9 objects, I show two just as exemple):

```
[
  {
    dt: 1643892957,
    temp: 14.9,
    description: 'few clouds',
    icon: '02d'
  },
  {
    dt: 1643889600,
    temp: 15,
    description: 'scattered clouds',
    icon: '03d'
  }
]
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: What is `url` in `JSON.parse(url)`?

Comment: `$(".city").html(result);` should be inside the `$.getJSON` callback function.

Comment: Just move it up one line in the code.

Comment: Doesn't work for me Barmar, but thank You anyway

Comment: I'll ask again: where does `url` come from?

Comment: You're never using the `data` parameter to the callback function.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You're right, url was on my last code. I change to data, but still not working.
Here is the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at script2.js:37:17
index2.html:48 Live reload enabled.
index2.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (script2.js:23:23)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28783)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:14035)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:16323)

Comment: Don't call `JSON.parse()`. That's already done by `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: Ok, but I need an array of objects and const urlJsonString returns me a string. How can I fix It not using JSON.parse?

Comment: `$.getJSON()` doesn't return the JSON string, it returns a `Deferred`, because it's an asynchronous function. The JSON is parsed and this parsed result is `data` in the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` parameter to the callback is the parsed JSON. You need to use this as the source for `current` and `daily`.

You're using `result` as both the HTML string and the array containing the results of all the `getData()` calls. You need different variables for this.

The call to `$(".city").html()` needs to be in the callback function so it can use all the variables that were assigned there.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=39.74362&lon=-8.80705&exclude=hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid=ecef7e88947b6303121bb900373e41d2", function(data) {
  const getData = ({
    dt,
    temp,
    weather: [{
      description,
      icon
    }]
  }) => {
    if (temp.day) temp = temp.day
    return {
      dt,
      temp,
      description,
      icon
    };
  }
  const {
    current,
    daily
  } = data;
  const result = [getData(current)]
  daily.forEach(obj => result.push(getData(obj)));

  const html = '';
  result.forEach(obj =>
    html += `Temperature: ${obj.temp} ºC<br>
        Day: ${obj.dt}<br>
        Description: ${obj.description}<br>
        ${iconCodes[obj.icon]}<br><br>`
  );
  $(".city").html(html);
});
```